# Android getX and getY for a custom view: strange behavior

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I need your help with an Android custom view and the methods `getX()` and `getY()`: I'm trying to paint a simple circle at view.getX() and view.getY(), but the circle hasn't its center in the top-left corner as I expect. See the image below (the custom View is the green rectangle):

[image: My custom view]

This is my custom view code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class PlotterView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    public PlotterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawCircle(this.getX(), this.getY(),5, paint);

    }
}
```

And this is the entire layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="calc.PlotFunctionActivity">

    <calc.PlotterView
        android:id="@+id/plotter"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_weight="8"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/plot_text_size"
            android:text="f(x)="
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/function"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/plot_text_size"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/plot_text_size"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/plot_button_label"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: use 0, 0 instead of getX(), getY() when drawing the circle

Comment: Doesn't getX and getY return the upper left corner of the View?

Comment: yes,  within the parent,  but the Canvas is translated so 0, 0 is a left-top corner of the View

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thank you, I missed the canvas translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pskink is totally right, you set a padding to your "base" linearlayout your plot view so when you call [getX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getX()) it returns you position of plotview in its parent layout (your base linearlayout) landmark (something corresponding to 16dp).

Then when you draw a circle you set circle center in plotview landmark so top-left corner of green view is (0,0). For now you can see the same translation between baselayout-plotview and plotview-circle center.